# How can I check for IP logs on the server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos7, firewall

I've a Centos 7 EC2 instance. I'm waiting a callback from another server, but the administrator says that he gets the error: 403 when trying to call the url
How can I check my server logs for this IP to see what's the problem?

Notes:
I allowed all traffic in security groups and acl
I disabled ConfigServer firewall
But I'm still facing the issue

Comment: Which web server software are you running? Apache?? An HTTP 403 status code is most probably not a firewall issue because your server apparently responds.

Comment: Yes, it's Apache. So what is probably the source of this error?

Comment: Increase the apache log level (see: https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/apache-logging-basics/) and look for the HTTP 403 error in the logs. If it is not there, maybe there is a proxy which is filtering the HTTP traffic?